# Implementing a wizard progress control in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a best way to implement a control like this in WPF?

[image: Wizard Progress Control]

I can easily replicate the text labels and the progress bar (without the circular "bumps" above each label) but I'd like to know if there's a control already out there, or a best practice, for creating this sort of control in WPF.

Comment: I don't think there is anything exactly like this right now.  I'm guessing you want the labels and percentages thereof to be dynamic right?

Comment: Preferably. I'd like to be able to drop in an `ItemsControl` (or other list) of labels and select a current step or index, but I'm open to other options.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It's hard to say what the *best practice* is in this case but here is how I would do it.

The wizard control in your screenshot looks like a combination of a `ProgressBar` and an `ItemsControl` and in this case it seems easier to me to derive from `ItemsControl` and implement the progress functionality than the other way around but it also depends on how you want it to work *(if you want a smooth progress or just light up the dots one-by-one for example)*.

Using a `UniformGrid` as `ItemsPanel` and the `ItemTemplate` below, we get the following look *(Steps is a `List` of strings)*
[image]

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Blue"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Adding a `DropShadowEffect` to the `ItemsPanel`, two `Path` elements to the `ItemTemplate` and two `DataTriggers` to determine if the current item is the first or last item to show/hide the left/right `Path` and we can get a pretty similar look to your screenshot
[image]

*ItemsPanel*

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <UniformGrid.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black"
                          BlurRadius="5"
                          Opacity="0.6"
                          ShadowDepth="0"/>
    </UniformGrid.Effect>
</UniformGrid>
```

*ItemTemplate*

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Data" Value="M0.0,0.0 L0.0,0.33 L1.0,0.33 L1.0,0.66 L0.0,0.66 L0.0,1.0"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="21"/>
            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource wizardBarBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeEndLineCap" Value="Square"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeStartLineCap" Value="Square"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Path Name="leftPath"/>
        <Path Name="rightPath" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Ellipse Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="{StaticResource wizardBarBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}"
                     Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="leftPath" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={markup:IsLastItemConverter}}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="rightPath" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

If you decide to use this approach you can probably work out how to get the rest of it going, like

- Implement this in a reusable custom control
- Only get the stroke (`DropShadowEffect`) on the progress-part and not in the text
- Implement the progress functionality etc.

Anyway, I uploaded a sample project with a custom control called `WizardProgressBar` and a demo project using it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ng9vfi6uwn1peot/WizardProgressBarDemo2.zip?dl=0

It looks like this
[image]

Things to note about the sample

- I ended up in a situation where I would get the `DropShadowEffect` on the progress-part and the headers or get a thin line between each item (as seen in the picture). I can't think of an easy way to get rid of it so maybe this isn't the best approach after all :)
- The progress-part is simple. It just has a value between 0-100 and then a converter decides if the item should be lit or not
- This control might have a small performance impact but I can't be sure since my computer seems to be running everything slow today...

**Update**

Made a few changes to the sample project where I split the presentation into two `ItemsControls` to get rid of the thin lines between each item. It now looks like this
[image]
Uploaded it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ng9vfi6uwn1peot/WizardProgressBarDemo2.zip?dl=0

**End of Update**

And here are the missing parts from the sample code above

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="wizardBarBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0.0" EndPoint="0.5,1.0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE4E4E4" Offset="0.25"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFededed" Offset="0.50"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFC" Offset="0.75"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

*IsLastItemConverter*

```
public class IsLastItemConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ContentPresenter contentPresenter = value as ContentPresenter;
        ItemsControl itemsControl = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(contentPresenter);
        int index = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(contentPresenter);
        return (index == (itemsControl.Items.Count - 1));
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public IsLastItemConverter() { }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Incredible, completely thorough answer. You deserve twice the bounty you received for this post. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Adam :) I made a few changes to the sample project that gets rid of the thin line between each item.

Comment: And you absolutely nailed it with the update. Many internets to you, my friend.

Comment: @Meleak I was hoping someone would work this out.  You should put this on your blog so Google can pick it up.  Very nice solution!

Comment: Hats off to you sir! I really like it, but I was struggling to make the steps clickable. Got it working in the end by adding buttons in the datacontext that emit commands that are bound in WizardProgressBar.

Comment: Do you still have the example code from your links on dropbox?  I tried the links above and they are currently dead

Comment: @John Hartsock: Yes, I've just been told that all the download links are missing. I'm gonna get them back asap

Comment: @JohnHartsock: I fixed the links in the post, they should work now. Apparently dropbox changed something.

Comment: Somewhat astounding that a larger entity (Telerik, DevExpress) didn't already build this, but I sure can't find it if they did. Many thanks to you @FredrikHedblad!

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar to this too. It's actually fairly easy in WPF. Basically I created 2 rectangles and overlapped them. The rectange in the background has the gradient colors and the rectangle in the foreground is the gray area used to cover up the gradient rectangle.

Simply adjust the width of the gray rectangle to give the illusion of the bar moving right or left.

Below is an image of what I did, along with the XAML.

[image]

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="2">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvasMain" Height="80" Width="330"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

        <Rectangle x:Name="recMainBar" Height="30" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="30" Stroke="Black" Width="300">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0,0" SpreadMethod="Reflect">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF5400A"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF54C816" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF31C614" Offset="0.996"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

        <!-- Cover of the bar -->
        <Rectangle x:Name="recMainBarCover" Height="30" Canvas.Top="30" Canvas.Left="0" Stroke="Black" Width="300" Fill="#FFEBEBEB"/>

        <Path Data="M8,34 L24.5,48.95" Fill="Green" Height="6.95" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="60" Width="5"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Height="15" Canvas.Left="2.0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0%" Canvas.Top="66.95" Width="16" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.051,-0.9"/>

        <Path Data="M8,34 L24.5,48.95" Fill="Green" Height="6.95" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="60" Width="5"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Height="15" Canvas.Left="30" Text="10%" Canvas.Top="66.95" Width="21" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.051,-0.9"/>

        <Path Data="M8,34 L24.5,48.95" Fill="Green" Height="6.95" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="60" Width="5"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Height="15" Canvas.Left="60" Text="20%" Canvas.Top="66.95" Width="21" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.051,-0.9"/>

        <Path Data="M8,34 L24.5,48.95" Fill="Green" Height="6.95" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="90" Canvas.Top="60" Width="5"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Height="15" Canvas.Left="90" Text="30%" Canvas.Top="66.95" Width="21" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.051,-0.9"/>

        <Path Data="M8,34 L24.5,48.95" Fill="Green" Height="6.95" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="120" Canvas.Top="60" Width="5"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Height="15" Canvas.Left="120" Text="40%" Canvas.Top="66.95" Width="21" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.051,-0.9"/>

        <Path Data="M8,34 L24.5,48.95" Fill="Green" Height="6.95" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="60" Width="5"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Height="15" Canvas.Left="145" FontWeight="Bold" Text="50%" Canvas.Top="66.95" Width="31" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.051,-0.9"/>

        <Path Data="M8,34 L24.5,48.95" Fill="Green" Height="6.95" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="60" Width="5"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Height="15" Canvas.Left="180" Text="60%" Canvas.Top="66.95" Width="27" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.051,-0.9"/>

        <Path Data="M8,34 L24.5,48.95" Fill="Green" Height="6.95" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="210" Canvas.Top="60" Width="5"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Height="15" Canvas.Left="210" Text="70%" Canvas.Top="66.95" Width="27" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.051,-0.9"/>

        <Path Data="M8,34 L24.5,48.95" Fill="Green" Height="6.95" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="240" Canvas.Top="60" Width="5"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Height="15" Canvas.Left="240" Text="80%" Canvas.Top="66.95" Width="27" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.051,-0.9"/>

        <Path Data="M8,34 L24.5,48.95" Fill="Green" Height="6.95" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="270" Canvas.Top="60" Width="5"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Height="15" Canvas.Left="270" Text="90%" Canvas.Top="66.95" Width="27" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.051,-0.9"/>

        <Path Data="M8,34 L24.5,48.95" Fill="Green" Height="6.95" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="60" Width="5"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Height="15" Canvas.Left="300" Text="100%" Canvas.Top="66.95" Width="27" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.051,-0.9"/>

        <TextBlock Name="txtTitle" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Black" Foreground="White" Height="30" Canvas.Left="0" Text="Confidence Factor" Canvas.Top="0" Width="330" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>

    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

Comment: As I said, recreating the text labels and the progress (without a bump over each label) is easy. I'm looking to exactly replicate the design I posted as a reusable control.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw the full progress indicator, set up a clipping mask for the progress indicator, and either alter or swap that mask with another mask at the appropriate points during your program's execution. If you wanted to get really creative, you could make a control that can define any arbitrary number of points.

This article tells you about generic clipping masks in Expression: http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc197119

This article shows you some code that may be a little more relevant:
http://blog.pixelingene.com/2009/02/animating-graphs-in-wpf-using-clipping-masks/
 and in this code, you could easily adjust the RectangleGeometry at runtime.

So what I get from all this reading and pondering is that you'd possibly try the Clip property on your blue progress indicator, and leave the background as-is.

That's the route I would probably take. Hope this helps!