# draw step indicator as custom controll

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I'm trying to create step indicator control that will show on which step user currently is.
I found on dribble some concept that I would like to create:

[image: dessign]

using very simple code I was able to create result like this:
[image: my result]

below is my code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StepIndicator
{
    public class StepIndicatorOne : Control
    {
        public StepIndicatorOne()
        {
            MinimumSize = new Size(300, 50);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            var g = e.Graphics;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            int steps = 3;
            int radiusBig = 20;
            int radiusSmall = 15;
            int bgHeight = 10;

            var gradientRect = new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.X + (ClientRectangle.Width - radiusBig*2)/(steps - 1),
                                             ClientRectangle.Y + ClientRectangle.Height/2 - radiusBig - 1, radiusBig*2, radiusBig*2);

            var lightGrayBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, Color.FromArgb(224, 227, 214), Color.LightGray, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
            var darkGrayBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(gradientRect, Color.DarkGray, Color.Gray, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
            var lightGreenBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, Color.FromArgb(206, 217, 79), Color.FromArgb(191, 201, 82), LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
            var darkGreenBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, Color.YellowGreen, Color.ForestGreen, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);

            g.FillRectangle(darkGrayBrush, ClientRectangle.X + radiusBig, ClientRectangle.Y + ClientRectangle.Height/2 - bgHeight/2 - 1,
                            ClientRectangle.Width - radiusBig*2, bgHeight);

            g.FillRectangle(lightGrayBrush, ClientRectangle.X + radiusBig, ClientRectangle.Y + ClientRectangle.Height/2 - bgHeight/2,
                            ClientRectangle.Width - radiusBig*2, bgHeight);

            for (int i = 1; i <= steps; i++)
            {
                g.FillEllipse(darkGrayBrush, ClientRectangle.X + ((ClientRectangle.Width - radiusBig*2)/(steps - 1))*(i - 1),
                              ClientRectangle.Y + ClientRectangle.Height/2 - radiusBig - 1, radiusBig*2, radiusBig*2);
                g.FillEllipse(lightGrayBrush, ClientRectangle.X + ((ClientRectangle.Width - radiusBig*2)/(steps - 1))*(i - 1),
                              ClientRectangle.Y + ClientRectangle.Height/2 - radiusBig, radiusBig*2, radiusBig*2);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= steps - 1; i++)
            {
                g.FillEllipse(darkGreenBrush,
                              ClientRectangle.X + ((ClientRectangle.Width - radiusBig*2)/(steps - 1))*(i - 1) + radiusBig - radiusSmall,
                              ClientRectangle.Y + ClientRectangle.Height/2 - radiusSmall - 1, radiusSmall*2, radiusSmall*2);
                g.FillEllipse(lightGreenBrush,
                              ClientRectangle.X + ((ClientRectangle.Width - radiusBig*2)/(steps - 1))*(i - 1) + radiusBig - radiusSmall,
                              ClientRectangle.Y + ClientRectangle.Height/2 - radiusSmall, radiusSmall*2, radiusSmall*2);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:
**Is it possible to create green shape as on design (green bar with circles and hole in one) but with border over it?**
I can draw rectangle with border and ellipse above it with border, but how can I combine those two shapes and have border around it (combine those two shapes into one) - is my only option creating complex path?

I know that winforms gdi+ can't use inner shadow, **but are there some other options to create nice looking effect simillar to inner glow?**
Right now I draw same shape with -1 offset and darker color, but effect isn't what I would like it to look.

I know that propably the best solution would be to switch to WPF and draw it there, I even found sample control on SO - [Implementing a wizard progress control in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691386/implementing-a-wizard-progress-control-in-wpf) but I **must stay** in Winforms

Comment: It would probably be easier to just create these as images (at least the complex parts) and draw the image.

Comment: @LarsTech - I was thinking about that, but with images I wont be able to customize the look of control without changing images. I would like to create one control with some options to config (colors of gradients, radius of circles, height of horizontal bar) with images those setting are worthless. I would like to try to create whole control with code, images are my last option. Thanks for suggestion, but for now I'll stay with code drawing for now :)

Comment: Try using a png with a transparent background and just draw the checkmark with the border.  Those checkmark examples you posted appear to be two different images for the small and large.

Comment: @LarsTech - checkmark will be an image. I'm planning to add ability to specify icon for every step as option to config, but I would like to draw everything else with code. My biggest problem now is how to combine horizontal bar and gray circles together, so that border will be drawn around it as a single shape, not around every one (hope my description makes sense :))

Answer (score 1):

Use a GraphicsPath for the complex path. Use a path gradient for the inner shadow.

Comment: Could You please post a simple examples of using this? I've tried using PraphicsPath but without any luck, I have problem drawing corners (there is line and circles on it, circly must be round, but corner between line and circle must be, hmm..a corner:) )

Comment: You can add both lines and arcs to a GraphicsPath. A rounded corner is an arc. I do not have any sample code; normally I would use VG.net for such a task.

Comment: VG.net looks nice, but it's to expensive for someone who is creating applications as a hobby and for school project. Besides that I was planning to create my component and release it as open source. I'll try with creating that Path by code.