# How to fill ItemsControl using an integer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I am trying to create a kind of progress bar control in WPF. It will be ellipses that fill in as each step completes. However, I am failing at coming up what I would consider a clean example (minimal code behind and waste). Here is what I have:

```
<ItemsControl>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Ellipse Fill="Blue" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then, I want to have two dependency properties:

- TotalSteps
- StepsCompleted

What I want is when `TotalSteps = 14` then there will be 14 ellipses and the fill would work off of a trigger using `StepsCompleted`, a math converter and the ellipse's index. However, I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this unless I create a dummy list that is created with blank objects that will act as my `DataContext`...but, that seems like a waste. Is there a way to fill the template based off of the number, and not need a backing List?

Alternatively, I would accept a solution that would be an override of the progress bar template. However, I found nothing, so the user control seemed the easiest

Comment: I think progressbar is there already in WPF. Then why re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: I will update my question, but the short answer is that this is not easily possible in the current progress bar

Comment: Possibly a grid that you could set a style as having an ellipse in each cell, then bind the number of Columns to progress?

Comment: Or, just `container.Children.Add(new Ellipse(...));` each time `StepCompleted` is called

Comment: check the following link. This might help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691386/implementing-a-wizard-progress-control-in-wpf